# Groovy findAll closure parameters

Tags: groovy, parameters, findall

I want use groovy `findAll` with my param to filtering closure

```
filterClosure = { it, param ->
  it.getParam == param
}
```

How can I now call this closure in findAll? Like below?

```
myColl = someColl.findAll(filterClosure ??? )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your collection was a list, you could use curry to populate the extra closure parameter with your object:

```
def someColl = ["foo", "bar", "foo", "baz", "foo"]

def filterClosure = { it, param -> it.getParam == param }

myColl = someColl.findAll(filterClosure.curry([getParam:'foo']))

assert ["foo", "foo", "foo"] == myColl
```

In the code above, the filterClosure "it" will be assigned what is passed to curry as a parameter and "param" is passed a collection item from findAll.  This wouldn't work for a Map collection since findAll for it takes a closure with either one or two parameters.